# Watir Caching on AWS EC2 instance for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, watir, one-time-password

I want to cache otp entries with watir

I tried this code in my local ;

```
args = %w[--disable-extension headless no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage disable-infobars --disable-gpu]
 @bw = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true, options: {args: args}  switches: %w[--user-data-dir= home/user/project/watir]
```

this kod is working and caching in my local directory "watir". This is perfect BUT when I tried this kod in AWS EC2 instance it's not working . I'm using this path in my EC2 ; switches: `%w[--user-data-dir=~/ec2-user/var/app/current/watir]` ı tried different path but I took same error.

```
 Error : Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: 
 cannot create default profile directory
```

in my opinion path is incorrect,  so I tried a lot of different path but still not working. How can I find true path in EC2 or Do you have another idea for cache otp with watir.